# Setting up an Autofixture for In-memory DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mocking, entity-framework-core, autofixture

I am currently trying to use Autofixture to create a pre-defined fixture as an implementation of [ICustomization](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/ICustomization.cs) for ApplicationDbContext using [In-Memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests).

```cs
public class ApplicationDbContextFixture : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        var specimenFactory = new SpecimenFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(CreateDbContext);
        fixture.Customize<ApplicationDbContext>(
                composer =>
                    composer.FromFactory(specimenFactory)
                );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private factory method to create a new instance of <see cref="ApplicationDbContext"/>
    /// </summary>
    private ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext()
    {
        var dbContextOptions = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .UseInMemoryDatabase("SomeDatabaseName")
                    .Options;
        var dbContext = new ApplicationDbContext(dbContextOptions);        
        return dbContext;
    }
}
```

Then, I will apply that customization to my Fixture as follows:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public void TestAddUsersToEmptyDatabase()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Fixture for ApplicationDbContext
        var fixture = FixtureFactory.CreateFixture();
        var applicationDatabaseFixture = new ApplicationDbContextFixture();
        fixture.Customize(applicationDatabaseFixture);

        // Fixture for users
        var randomUser = fixture.Create<AppUser>();
        var normalUser = fixture.Create<AppUser>();
        var adminUser = fixture.Create<AppUser>();

        // Act & Assert
        // Run the test against one instance of the context
        // Use a clean instance of the context for each operation too
        using (var dbContext = fixture.Create<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            Assert.Empty(dbContext.Users);
            dbContext.Users.Add(randomUser);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var dbContext = fixture.Create<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            dbContext.Users.AddRange(normalUser, adminUser);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var dbContext = fixture.Create<ApplicationDbContext>())
        {
            Assert.NotEmpty(dbContext.Users);
            Assert.NotNull(dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Id == randomUser.Id));
            Assert.NotNull(dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Id == normalUser.Id));
            Assert.NotNull(dbContext.Users.SingleOrDefault(_ => _.Id == adminUser.Id));
        }
    }
```

FixtureFactory.CreateFixture implementation

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Factory method to declare a single <see cref="IFixture"/> for unit tests applications
    /// </summary>
    internal static class FixtureFactory
    {
        internal static IFixture CreateFixture()
        {
            var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(
                new AutoMoqCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });

            return fixture;
        }
    }
```

Now in my unit test, asserting the `Assert.Empty(dbContext.Users);` will throw `System.NotImplementedException : The method or operation is not implemented.` because the `DbSet<AppUser> Users` generated from Autofixture is a DynamicProxy.

See image [dbContext.Users as DynamicProxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xAAf.png)

Oddly enough if I inspect the breakpoints from the factory method (ie. `CreateDbContext()`) called from the `fixture.Create<ApplicationDbContext>()`, the DbSet Users is of the expected type.

See image [dbContext.Users as InternalDbSet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo7em.png)

Optionally, I do aware that I can replace all the usage of `dbContext.Users` to `dbContext.Set<User>()` and that would make the unit test pass but the problem is that in the actual class, I am using the `dbContext.Users` for [IQueryables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netcore-3.1) and database operations, so I still need to stick with it if possible.

Hence, I would need help to know why does AutoFixture used my factory method to generate the instance for my ApplicationDbContext but all the `DbSet<>` properties inside it are mocked when resolved by the ISpecimenBuilder. Is there a way to remedy this?

I've post the similar question in [their Github](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/1170) but it has been not active recently, so i also asked here.

Kindly please understand I only started to use Autofixture 2 days ago. So if there's something that I write wrong or there's a misconception in any Design Patterns, please kindly wrote a comment so that I can take it as a lesson.

**Update 1**:
So i tried to use initialized a plain fixture without any AutoMoq customization (ie. `fixture = new Fixture()`) and this time it throws a `AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath` exception, complaining that it is unable to resolve DbSet property within the ApplicationDbContext. At this point, I was thinking if anyone know how to use a Relay or ISpecimenBuilder to tell Autofixture to use/call/implement all `DbSet<T>` properties within the ApplicationDbContext with `dbContext.Set<T>` because that would work if I replace all usage of DbSets in my unit tests, but as I mentioned, all IQueryable are return from DbSets so i cannot simply just replace it in ApplicationDbContext.

**Update 2**:
I remove and simplify the creation of ApplicationDbContext from my factory method CreateDbContext() since it will cause confusion from the code complexity.

Comment: Should you assert like this: `Assert.Empty(dbContext.Users.ToList());` ? You need to run EF execution command, which is `ToList()` in this case.

Comment: Hi @Olegl, adding it ToList() as in my original code won't work as mentioned too because Autofixture is mocking all the properties of type ```DbSet<>``` as mocks since i used the ```AutoMoqCustomization``` from my factory method.

As the time i wrote Update 1 now, i found that using plain Fixture without any customizations exception for my ```ApplicationDbContextFixture``` would throw me a ```AutoFixture.ObjectCreationExceptionWithPath``` exception, where Autofixture is unable to derive an implementation for DbSet<Users>.

Comment: While its possible to set every fixture for every type of DbSet<T> for every related property in the ApplicationDbContext, that would be tedious since i have lots of DbSets. Also, dbContext.Set<T> would work fine even in my original case, so i was thinking some sort of solution that would use a Relay or another ISpecimenBuilder that would help to resolve all DbSet<T> to automatically derive from dbContext.Set<T> but i am lacking knowledge on how to handle that with Autofixture atm.

Comment: What are you trying to test here? Seems like you unit test Entity Framework itself

Comment: The unit test is POC to show that calling ```fixture.Create<ApplicationDbContext>``` doesnt works as I intended. If you look into [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#writing-tests), this is how you write test doubles to mock the behaviour for EF.

To quote from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/):
"You may want to test components using something that approximates connecting to the real database, without the overhead of actual database I/O operations."

Comment: Btw, i simplify my factory method since at second glance the original implementation can be simplify as written in **Update 2**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve from your post.

I think what you actually need, is to test your code that happens to use EntityFramework.
If that's the case you might want to have a look at this library, I have created [EntityFrameworkCore.AutoFixture](https://github.com/aivascu/EntityFrameworkCore.AutoFixture). It uses the In-Memory database provider as well as SQLite in-memory provider.

Here's a sample of what the tests can look like.

```cs
public class InMemoryDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public InMemoryDataAttribute()
        : base(() => new Fixture()
            .Customize(new InMemoryCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

```cs
[Theory, InMemoryData]
public async Task SampleTest([Frozen] ApplicationDbContext context, IEnumerable<AppUser> users)
{
    // Arrange
    await context.Users.AddRangeAsync(users);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    // Force EF Core to reload entities from the database
    context.Users.Clear();

    // Act
    var actual = context.Users.ToList();

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal(users, actual, new IdentiyUserComparer());
}
```

Have a look at the readme for some more code samples. If you have any questions drop me a message or open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Hi thx for the reply @Andrew. I have tried this and left my comments in Github thread. For here, I would mark this as the answer since it meets the basic requirement i was looking for (ie. To create fixtures for DbContext using Autofixture and In-Memory Db). However, i did face some issues so im leaving you some questions over the original github post.

Cheers for the great work.

Comment: @UnBroKeN thank you. The issue you mentioned on the GitHub thread is now fixed and available for download in the latest preview build. A full release should follow soon.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, except with a link to some library elsewhere. It may very well do everything the OP needed, but it's hardly helpful for those who followed a link here looking for immediate help on getting something working from this site. If you were to show how to use this library to solve the question, that would be a much better answer.

Comment: @HereticMonkey the process of initializing a DbContext is complex enough that it required a separate library. That's not to mention that the process is different from version to version. Would you have preferred the entire content of the library dumped on SO? In terms of examples the readme provides enough information to get you started on any scenario.

Comment: No, the entire library should not be posted. As I said, showing how to use the library to solve this specific question would be adequate. We want answers to questions on this site, not links to answers to questions.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I've added code samples. Hope this helps.